# Javascript game input loses focus

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

So, I am coding a game that will use keyboard input.  I track the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events similar to here:

http://nokarma.org/2011/02/27/javascript-game-development-keyboard-input/index.html

However, there are use cases where `Keyup`/`Keydown` events can be missed.  I tried adding a blur to my body element, but there are use cases where it doesn't blur.  The simplest example I can give is if a user right clicks on an area outside of the document, say on a book mark, the browser doesn't give any events to the DOM and the context menu starts getting keyboard inputs.  SO, if the user was holding the UP arrow and whilst still holding the up arrow, right clicks on a bookmark, and then releases the arrow key, the corresponding `KeyUp` event will never be given to the browser.  If the user presses the key again, then the key will 'reset', but that is still a bug.

For Chrome and Firefox I could use the PointerLock API, but I wanted to know if there was something else I could do.  I thought about blurring automatically if the mouse leaves the client area, but when I'm playing games I usually move the mouse to a bottom corner.  AFAIK one cannot manually poll the keyboard.  Are there any work arounds that I have missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if it would help but in your implementation, on the keydown method change a variable somewhere to indicate it was pressed.

Also run a timer that resets the value every x ms to unpressed (if it is still being pressed the keydown method should fire within the same update)

Then on the keyup method change the variable to unpressed.

This should give a more reliable indication if the buttons are pressed and I previously used a simular method on a java game that worked beautifully!

Comment: The time between key presses seems to vary quite a bit, so I am going to have them expire after a "safe" number of milliseconds.  Every keydown event will reset the the timer.  Still this is the exact kind of work around I was looking for.  Many thanks.